# What value, and type, is this burnt out resistor?

Tags: resistors

It's from the door control board of a Neff dishwasher, near a bunch of HF3FA relays and caps, other larger parts and the power input.

It broke in two and appears to have a faint wire winding just under its green coating.

[image: Resistor]

Comment: So, what did you infer so far from the resistor color code?

Comment: I'd say without a service manual it is impossible to identify the resistor value, because the two colour bands are burnt so badly that their original colour is unknown. Besides resistors don't burn up themselves. There was or still is a fault somewhere and unless that is now fixed, the new resistor will burn up too. Try contacting dishwasher repair service to have it fixed.

Comment: @SolarMike I found that its in the G range which seems unlikely, so I have no faith in the colours due to what Justme said.

Comment: You deserve some credit for posting a clear picture at least!

Comment: In such cases, you sometimes can measure the remaining resistances from the broken zone to the two terminals to get a hint, what the original resistance was. This, together with some still readable color rings can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Googling `AKO709004` a number on the board, I found a full fixit for exactly the issue!

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Bosch+Dishwasher+Dishwasher+SRI45T45EU-18+-+Control+Module+Repair/128617

Thanks for your answers.

Interestingly it's 100 Ohm, 3W fireproof. Nothing like what it's bands suggest.

Comment: The last band just got cooked and turned white. You should still find what caused the initial problem and repair that (as per the link) before just replacing the resistor.

Comment: Although text talks about 100Ω,  picture shows 22Ω, 5% resistor, which does agree with the 2 colors showing.

Comment: Damn. So it does. Thanks for pointing that out. I've already bought and received all the replacement bits. Though the other photo of all the parts does show a 100Ω - guess there's only one way to find out - https://guide-images.cdn.ifixit.com/igi/oLacHUt5BbbB4dOS.full

Comment: Thanks to everyone here. I managed to replaced various parts and the little AC/DC IC and it worked!!